# SPOJ LASTDIG, getting TLE

Tags: c++

Below is my code for the problem. I am getting TLE. Can anyone tell me how to fix it.
Here is the problem statement:

Nestor was doing the work of his math class about three days but he is tired of make operations a lot and he should deliver his task tomorrow. His math’s teacher gives two numbers a and b. The problem consist in find the last digit of the potency of base a and index b. Help Nestor with his problem. You are given two integer numbers: the base a (0 <= a <= 20) and the index b (0 <= b <= 2,147,483,000), a and b both are not 0. You have to find the last digit of a^b.

Input

The first line of input contains an integer t, the number of test cases (t <= 30). t test cases follow. For each test case will appear a and b separated by space.

Output

For each test case output an integer per line representing the result.

Example

Input:
2
3 10
6 2

Output:
9
6

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {   
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);

    int num;
    unsigned int pow;
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&num);

        scanf("%d",&pow);
        int z=1;
        if(num==0&&pow==0)
            printf("1");
        else
        {
            while(pow!=0)
            {
                z=z*num;
                z=z%10;
                pow--;
            }
            printf("%d\n",z);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if i input t = -1?

Comment: that's just for test cases and -1 is irrelevant

Comment: How is it possible to use `scanf` and `printf` by including `iostream` header? Is this C or C++?

Comment: @CoolGuy i think, the _same_ way it is tagged both `c` and `c++` :P

Comment: Earlier i did it with cin and cout but somewhere i read scanf and printf is faster so i used it, and yeah iostream works with scanf and printf.

Comment: Your `if` is unneccessary,I think

Comment: @CoolGuy in the spoj forum people said output for 0^0 should be shown as 0

Comment: If that is the case,you print 1 not 0 and the question also mentions that "a
and b both are not 0"`

Comment: @CoolGuy it does print 1 and not 0

Comment: But you just said that it should print 0! Also,remove `z=z%10` from the loop and print `z%10` instead of `z` in the `printf` after that loop

Comment: @CoolGuy Sorry for the previous error it should print 1. And I removed as you said but it still gives TLE

Comment: If this is C,try replacing the first two lines with `#include <stdio.h>` or if C++,replace them with `#include <cstdio>`. You can further shorten the program by moving `pow--` in the condition of the inner `while` loop

Comment: If I remove pow-- then while is stuck in infinite loop

Comment: I said to "move" to the condition of the inner `while` loop and not to "remove" it.

Comment: http://www.kodemonk.com/lastdig-the-last-digit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `b` is too high, a simple approach such as yours is bound to give a TLE. You can solve this problem using `Modular Exponentiation`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation